# Resources for Meteor app which can only be accessed by the server-side.

Tags: javascript, meteor, server-side

Is there a way to store private resources (binary files) for a Meteor app, which can only be accessed by the server side code?

If I put them into the server directory, they are not contained within the tarball created by `meteor bundle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to put them in the 'private' directory.  Documentation of app structure is [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp).